# Excel 2010 VBA Copy Data from Multiple Excel Files

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have search and searched for this and have come close but not perfect. Here it goes...

What I need is a code to work through other excel work books in succession and copy data. The files will be named 1,2,3,4 etc all the up to about 60 max. I have some code that will open all the files for my which works great. Next I need it to go into all of the work books and copy a set up data and return it to the main workbook which I have been able to do as well. Here are my problems...

1. I know there must be a way to write the code one time and have it work through the remaining files. IE. if the first file is named 1.csv can the code say to do it on 1.csv, then on 1.csv + 1 meaning 2.csv and then loop out? It seems like it should be able to do it. I don't want to have to manually work my way through writing the same code to copy from 1.csv all the way to 60.csv
2. If there is a way to loop it then how to I end the end if part. IE one week there might be 37 files and the next 40 and so on. I want it to start at file 1.csv and work until it gets to the last active file either 37.csv or 60.csv and then end if there is no 38.csv file.

Here is the basic recorded code I have.

```
   Public Sub testr()
  Dim filenum As Integer
  Dim lastrow As Long

  filenum = 1
  On Error GoTo my_handler

  Do
    Windows(filenum & ".CSV").Activate
    Range("A25").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("test.xlsm").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    lastrow = Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    filenum = filenum + 1
  Loop

my_handler:
  MsgBox "All done."
  Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Any help that anyone could give me would be amazing! Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, for the code you have now, you need to at least edit to look like this:

```
Public Sub testr()
  Dim filenum As Integer
  filenum = 1
  On Error GoTo my_handler

  Do
    Windows(filenum & ".CSV").Activate
    Range("A25").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("test.xlsm").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A1").Select
    filenum = filenum + 1
  Loop

my_handler:
  MsgBox "All done."
  Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: WORKED! Macro ran smoothly. As per usual though, another issue which I think will be easy to correct. The data that it is copying from the csv files is pasting over itself. I tried adding a code to go to the next empty cell and then paste, but it isn't work. I used this code.                                                                           LastRow = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

Comment: Checked off the answer accepted! For the last row, it will always be different. One CSV file might have 12 rows of data and the next 30 and so on. I want to copy all the data from 1.csv and paste it and then copy 2.csv and paste it right below the data from 1.csv and move on. I had that working in my initial code with the piece I sent you, but when I put that piece in this one it doesn't do it.

Comment: Not working. It keeps just pasting in A1 over the other data. I read through the other link and I don't see anything that helps what I am looking for. I edited my code so you could see what I have.

Comment: No dice on that one. The sheet comes back completely blank with that. I thought it was maybe because the sheet was blank to begin with so I put a header in and started the paste at A2, but that didn't work either.

Comment: So I replaced activesheet.paste with your code and I am getting a application defined or object defined error on that line.

Comment: I got it! I used this. Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

Comment: Last question on this, these files that I am pulling data from, they aren't already name 1,2,3,4,5, etc. They need to be renamed manually. Is there a way that this could not look for "1.csv" and just look for active excel windows so I don't have to rename all of them. Sometimes there are as many as 60 and that is very manual

Comment: You might try playing with the [Windows object members](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetId=HV805547719990&lcid=1033&NS=EXCEL%2EDEV&Version=12&pid=CH080554769&CTT=4) to see what works. I'd recommend looking into the .Count and .Item properties.

Comment: What if I were to rename all the files at once so that they become 1 (1) 1 (2)? Could I then increase the (1) (2) (3) by 1 each time in the macro versus increasing the name if the csv by 1? I tried making filenum = (1) and then adding the +1 to that but it didn't like that

Comment: Got this one too! Just wrote another script to rename all the files in a folder for me. Thank you again for all of your help. You are amazing!

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping all this in a DO...LOOP. If you don't know how many .csv files you'll be working with, just put in an error handler to quit once no more files are found.

You can use string concatenation to make the filenames change: for example, using a variable called filenum, if filenum = 1 then filenum & ".csv" would be "1.csv," if filenum = 2 then filenum & ".csv" would be "2.csv," etc.

For example:

```
Public Sub testr()
Dim filenum As Integer
filenum = 1
On Error GoTo my_handler
Do
  Windows(filenum & ".CSV").Activate
  'rest of code goes here
filenum = filenum + 1
Loop

my_handler:
  MsgBox "All done."
Exit Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Aaron! How would I add the concatenation to the code for this? The idea makes sense in text, but how does it translate in VBA? Additionally, how do I use the loop and concatenate together?

Comment: OK I got it to go with your code, but on the loop back up it tells me the the "Windows(filenum & ".CSV).Activate" is a sub script out of range and wont move on to the next file or 2.CSV and errors. Any thoughts?

Comment: You may try making a string for the filename, and use that string for the Windows.Activate method. For example, dim file_name as string; file_name = filenum & ".csv"; Windows(file_name).Activate

Comment: Can't get that to work. It doesn't like the Windows Activate method with Windows(file_name)

Comment: Just checking, but is that window actually open? I'm assuming your original code from above - Windows("1.CSV").Activate - worked properly?

Comment: Yea I have all the csv files open when running. The original code worked perfect, but the catch was that I never know how many csv files I will have so I was looking for a way to write it so it just went until it didn't find any more csv files and then end

Comment: I checked this with my setup, using dummy windows 1.csv, 2.csv, and 3.csv. Code works just fine as originally proposed in my answer above. Maybe the problem is something else, possibly that you haven't modified your code to include my_handler? I'll edit my answer once more to show how to do that.

Comment: Hmmm..probably. So I tried again and still get and error. Maybe it is the way I am putting the code in there? I am declaring the DIM at the top and then copying your code exactly the way it is into the section below and then adding the rest of it. Now I am getting a "Label not defined" error and it looks like that error relates to the my_handler. Do I have to do anything additional with the my_handler below the loop?

Comment: Is there any way you could edit your question, then at the end of the question show what you have at this point?

Comment: I edited my question above for you. By the way, thank you very much for all the help with this!!